# xdg-desktop-portal always crashes at startup in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

`xdg-document-portal` always crashes when Ubuntu 19.10 starts up. Is there a way to prevent it crashing or to disable it without interfering with system functionality?

update:

It crashes almost on every system boot.

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Fri Mar  6 13:18:09 2020
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 19.10
ExecutablePath: /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
ExecutableTimestamp: 1578493564
ProcCmdline: /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
ProcCwd: /home/usr
ProcEnviron:
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
 PATH=(custom, user)
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
ProcMaps:
```

update2:

Look at the syslog, I have error like this:

```
xdg-document-portal.service: Failed to set 'memory.limit_in_bytes' attribute on '/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1
000.service/xdg-document-portal.service' to '-1': No such file or directory
xdg-document-portal.service: Failed to set 'pids.max' attribute on '/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/x
dg-document-portal.service' to '4915': No such file or directory
```

Comment: How does this crash manifest itself? What exactly happens? Does the crash prevent the system from functioning totally or partially? If, it's partial, what works, what doesn't? My `/var/crash` folder is empty in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: _usr_libexec_xdg-document-portal.1000.crash  _usr_libexec_xdg-document-portal.1000.upload  _usr_libexec_xdg-document-portal.1000.uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to fix the issue simply run the following command in Terminal:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade xdg-desktop-portal
```

Comment: xdg-desktop-portal is already the newest version

Comment: I had same issue and followed this answer for a fix.  The upgrade did in fact update xdg-desktop-portal to a new version, or at least it asked me if it was okay to add more to storage space and I hit "Y" to continue.  This was needed after completely wiped hard drive new install single OS boot system using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - which was needed after Grub Customizer corrupted Grub 2 on a multi-boot system. Full backup, HDD wipe, reinstall.  Thanks for the help.