# xdg-desktop-portal.service crashes at startup in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: startup

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10. xdg-desktop-portal.service fails to start.
I've been looking for a solution on [xdg-desktop-portal always crashes at startup in Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187668/xdg-desktop-portal-always-crashes-at-startup-in-ubuntu-19-10)

But my xdg-desktop-portal is up to date. The problem persists at startup and I noticed lags in the gnome interface.

Anybody has a solution ?

Comment: How does this crash manifest itself? What errors have you gathered from logs?